# How does this Gremlin query be executed?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I'm trying to understand how the following **Gremlin** query will be executed?

```
g.V('california').repeat(out('interstate')).emit().repeat(out('highway')).emit().tree()
```

I assume the travesal finds all the **nodes/vertices** from `california` with `interstate` **edge** and for each of those `interstate vertex`, it finds all the `highways`. Then it makes a tree structure with `interstate` and it's `highways`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from `california`, traversers follow all out-directed `interstate` edges until there's no more `interstate` edge left. From all vertices, that were found along the path, the traversers will then follow all out-directed `highway` edges, again until there's no `highway` edge left.

Both repetitions can very well run into a cyclic path (meaning, the traversal will never come to an end). However, should an end be found, all paths will be merged into a tree structure.